# I need help to correctly format this table

Tags: python

I need help formating this table to where it only prints to the 3rd decimal place for each stat. I also want the stats to be directly underneath the correct label

```
player=input("Player name:")
hits=int(input("Hits:"))
ab=int(input("At Bats:")) 
walks=int(input("Walks:")) 
hbp=int(input("Hit By Pitch:")) 
tb=int(input("Total Bases:"))

ba=hits/ab
oBp=(hits+walks+hbp)/(ab+walks+hbp)
sLg= tb/ab
iSo= sLg - ba
oPs= oBp + sLg
format_string = '{name:9}{avg:4}{obp:5}{slg:4}{iso:4}{ops:4}'


print(format_string.format(name='Player', avg='AVG',obp='OBP',slg='SLG',iso='ISO',ops='OPS'))

print('-' * 64)

print(format_string.format(name=player, avg=ba, obp=oBp, slg=sLg,iso=iSo,ops=oPs))
```

[image]

Comment: the image is a picture of my current output

Comment: What problem are you running into when you try to implement this formatting? This site expects you to have specific questions rather than just requests to add features to your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to move this way, it may help:

```
format_string = '{name:9}{avg:4}{obp:5}{slg:4}{iso:4}{ops:4}'
format_string_f = '{name:9}{avg:2.1f} {obp:3.1f}  {slg:2.1f} {iso:2.1f} {ops:2.1f}'

print(format_string.format(name='Player', avg='AVG',obp='OBP',slg='SLG',iso='ISO',ops='OPS'))

print('-' * 64)

print(format_string_f.format(name=player, avg=ba, obp=oBp, slg=sLg,iso=iSo,ops=oPs))
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZz9U.png)

Answer (score 0):

To only print 3 decimal points, you have to restrict it by using a float. `{:.3f}`
Also to make your labels look neat, I feel like everything can be inputted using a dict where the key and values will correspond to each other.